# What is the difference between "char* p" and "char *p" in C?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define KOREA "대한민국"

char* My_strcpy(char* dest, const char* src);
```

What is the difference between "char* p" and "char *p"?

Comment: Thanks for all answers.. This is my first question..

Comment: Before answering, please try to find duplicates for questions that have obviously been asked many times before.

Comment: Okay, I'll heed your comment.

Comment: Thank you for posting this question. Any novice programmer in C might look for this question. Google brought me here :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference, it is only a matter of style.

Like John Skeet wrote in a former comment (for another topic):

> Different people have different conventions for that.

Comment: thank you ! your answer is very fast.

Answer (score 2):

`char* p` and `char *p` are *exactly* equivalent.

In many ways, you ought to write `char *p` since, really, `p` is a *pointer* to `char`. But as the years have ticked by, most folk regard `char*` as the *type* for `p`, so `char* p` is possibly more common.

But do note though that `char* p, q;` actually declares `p` as a *pointer* to a `char` and `q` as a `char`! If you wanted two pointers, you would have to write `char *p, *q;` or the incredibly obfuscated

`char* p, *q;`.

Comment: I feel declaring p and q on separate lines is a better deal - `char *p; char *q;` just to avoid any confusion related to placement of asterisk. But this is just a one time confusion it seems until one gets to know the basics of pointer declaration semantics.

Answer (score 1):

`char* p` and `char *p` are the same. As is `char*p` and `char * p`.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning `char*p and char * p`. I've never used them :). I've always been using the other two.